# I want to search a pattern from one file in another

Tags: linux

I have two files with following contents

**file 1:**

```
9/09a-A5
9/09a-A18
9/09b- 2B
9/09a-A9
9/09b- 7
9/09a-A11
9/09a-A14
9/09c- 16
9/09b- 5
9/09b- 12
9/09a-A25
9/09a-A10Y
9/09a-A17Z
9/09a-A12Z
9/09b- 4Z
9/09a-A26Y
9/09a-A13
9/09a-A27
9/09a-A19
9/09a-A10
9/09a-A17Y
9/09a-A4
9/09a-A7
9/09a-A15
9/09b- 1
9/09a-A19Z
9/09a-A26
9/09a-A16
9/09a-A22Z
9/09a-A10Z
9/09a-A26Z
9/09a-A13Z
9/09b- 9
9/09b- 4
```

**file 2**

```
9/09b- 2
9/09b- 2A
9/09b- 2B
9/09b- 4Z
9/8B-13
9/9A-11
9/9A-13
9/9A-13Z
9/9A-14
9/9A-6
9/9A-8
9/9A-A13
9/9B-1
9/9B-10
9/9B-12
9/9B-3
9/9B-4
9/9B-5
9/9B-7
9/9B-9
9/9C-15
9/9C-16
9/9D-17
```

I want to take row 1 from file 1 and search for same name in file 2, if it is there then print. Please note that there are spaces and upper and lower cases to be ignored while searching.
here result should be

```
9/09b- 2B
9/09b- 5
9/09c- 16
9/09b- 12
9/09b- 4Z
9/09a-A13
9/09b- 1
9/09b- 9
9/09b-
```

Comment: did you try anything before posting question here ?

Comment: yes, Rahul i tried but unable to resolve the issue of having spaces in pattern. Pl help

Comment: Try `grep -xF -f file1 file2`.

Comment: it is giving only two outputs??

Comment: You say that the matching should be performed ignoring spaces and character case, but you also seem to want to ignore some of the zeroes. Please clarify the question.

Comment: Yes, zeroes are also an issue. it could be 9/09b- 1 or 9/9b- 1. so it should search to find the partial pattern

Answer (score -2):

```
for i in `cat file1 | sed -e 's/ //g'`
do
    echo file1:${i},file2:`grep $i file2`
done
```

or something like that...

or maybe:

```
for i in `cat file1 | sed -e 's/ //g'`
do 
    for o in `cat file2 | sed -e 's/ //g'`
    do
        [[ $i == $o ]] && echo We have a match: $i $o
    done
done
```

Comment: It does not work as some name are having spaces in both the files and those values are ignored. e.g 9/09b -3 is same in file 2.