# Partial match of first file content from another and write in third file

Tags: text-processing, files

Given file 1...

```
2/26a- 6
23/26a- 20z
23/26A-18
```

and file 2...

```
2/26a-6
23/26a- 20Z
23/26A-18
25/2a -18
22/34B-19
```

How can I search file 2 for the contents of file 1 ? Here the output should be:

```
2/26a-6
23/26a- 20Z
23/26A-18
```

(So not an exact match, but there is some shared content). Matching should be case-insensitive.

Comment: how your output would matched this line `2/26a-6` ? Space differs in both files.

Comment: Repost of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/301443/i-want-to-search-a-pattern-from-one-file-in-another

Comment: @Rahul He can truncate white-spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
tr -d " \t\r" < file1 > X

tr -d " \t\r" < file2 > Z
```

And then:

```
grep --ignore-case -Fxf X Z
```

Done!

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the contents of file1 to replace sequences of one or more whitespace characters with a regular expression representing zero or more whitespace characters:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/[[:space:]]*/g' file1
2/26a-[[:space:]]*6
23/26a-[[:space:]]*20z
23/26A-18
```

and then use that as a pattern file for your case-insensitive grep:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/[[:space:]]*/g' file1 | grep -if- file2
2/26a-6
23/26a- 20Z
23/26A-18
```

NOTE: this approach will only work if the entries in your `file1` do not contain other special characters - if they do, then these will need to be suitably escaped.

Comment: Thanks, very close but issue here is that file 2 also has spaces in some of the names.

Comment: Actually i am getting some of the names from file2 ? I have 180 entries in file1 and 4500 in file2. so the output should be 180 (similar to file 1)  from file 2.

Comment: @user183218 it should handle spaces in the names in file2 - for example it is clearly matching `23/26a- 20Z`. If you want further help then please provide a more representative sample of your files.

Comment: Actually it is long list having 5000 entries. How to send it ? Pl suggest.